# Web API resulting in Memory Usage 99%, Didn't drop down

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, azure

I am using MVC 4 & have created a Standalone Utility application which sends data after every 30 minutes to the cloud database.

I can notice on the cloud server CPU Memory Usage goes up to 99% & i have to restart the IIS when this happens. There is no dropping of the Memory when ti reaches above 90%.

Is there some thing that i can change in my code? Or How to handle this?

Following is the Code :-
API Calling Method :-

```
List<IEnumerable<Logs>> listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<Logs>>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count(); i += 50)
                            {
                                listOfLists.Add(lst.Skip(i).Take(50));
                            }
                            int count = 0;
                            foreach (var data in listOfLists)
                            {
                                count = count + data.Count();
                                string url = UrlLink + "/api/SaveEmployee?Schema=" + Schema;
                                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                                request.Timeout = 20000000; request.Proxy = null; request.KeepAlive = true;
                                request.KeepAlive = true;
                                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                                request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, *"; request.Proxy = null;
                                request.Method = "Post";
                                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                                {
                                    streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                                    {
                                        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                                        var rawJson = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                                        lst = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Logs>>(rawJson));

                                                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                                                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                                                {                                                      
                                                    sw.WriteLine(data.Count());
                                                }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ee)
                                {

                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    request.Abort();
                                }
}
```

API Method :-

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public void SaveEmployee(string Schema)
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(Schema))
            {
                ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var d1 = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                var rawJson = new StreamReader(d1).ReadToEnd();
            }
         }
```

Comment: is this azure web app or standalone VM ?? did u try increasing the number of instances. ?

Answer (score 1):

> var rawJson = new StreamReader(d1).ReadToEnd();

According to your API Method, I found you don't release the StreamReader resource. I guess this is the reason why your CPU memory is 99%.

StreamReader, StreamWriter, BinaryReader and BinaryWriter all close/dispose their underlying streams when you call Dispose on them. They don't dispose of the stream if the reader/writer is just garbage collected though - you should always dispose of the reader/writer, preferably with a using statement.

So I suggest you could change the webapi method as below:

```
       ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
       var d1 = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(d1))
                {
                    string rawJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    //....Then you could return the response
                }
```

Comment: I implemented the code but still Memory goes up to 97%.

Comment: Could you please tell me your web api hosting on the azure web app or azure VM ??

Comment: Does you VM host multiple web application? I guess maybe some other application or software uses the memory. I suggest you could use task manager or some other tools to locate which process uses the memory.